# Is it possible to use an embbeded control in Excel to preview video feed from webcam using DirectShow?

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, directshow, directshow.net

There are a quite a few of sources to get a video stream from webcam into a picturebox embedded in a userform.

- [Preview a camera in DirectShow and capture a still image - in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465932/preview-a-camera-in-directshow-and-capture-a-still-image-in-vb-net)
- [How do i use attached webcams to take still image in my application](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9a0e785-fcf2-4f32-a582-d2c5461ed05d/how-do-i-use-attached-webcams-to-take-still-image-in-my-application?forum=vbgeneral#45d106b0-91be-46f4-a0d4-4d997ac31cb8)

However, I am trying to do something a little neater, basically have a the preview of the video stream from webcam in a control that is embedded directly into the sheet rather than on a floating userform. I am not sure if this possible. I would very much appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Sorry, not sure of how to do this but I did want to comment to whoever voted to close that the existing close vote (move to Serverfault) is invalid.  This is not a Serverfault question.

Comment: With an own ActiveX/OLE Control, this should be possible. We have done so for IE 6 a long time ago (10+ years). I don't think it is possible with VBScript only. Btw: what to you mean with webcam? An USb-Webcam or an IP-Webcam? An IP-Webcam has just JPEG-Images you can show.

Comment: Well in my case it will be the internal camera of the computer, but I think this should equally work. with Excel you can insert an embedded Active X image control, but I am not sure it will work in this case. So basically what you are saying it requires a custom ActiveX control, that maybe beyond me at this stage.

Comment: A good idea to use Excel as a spreadsheet, not a database, not a full-blown EUCA, and certainly not as a replacement for Skype. A really important part of any Engineering field, particularly Software, is using the right tool for the job. While you could use a 15 year old ActiveX control to do it - you would be much better off using VSTO and embedding the video in a floating control. This idea has been discussed in the past, eg: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?q=embed%20video%20in%20excel%20cell - its just not good practice.

Comment: If you can write a .Net WinForm UserControl to view your video stream, then you should be able to produce a ActiveX UserControl that you can utilize in Excel.  Get the [Microsoft InteropForms Toolkit 2.1 ](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3264).  Even though it was originally intended to allow .Net UC usage in VB6, it works fine to write UCs for use in Excel.  As a test, I just wrote one that used the Windows Media Player and it played the video fine as a UserControl on the worksheet.  Start VS as an Admin as it needs to be able to register the control.

Answer (score 1):

(Answer from TnTinMn's comment - Posting as an answer to remove from 'Unanswered' queue)

If you can write a .Net WinForm UserControl to view your video stream, then you should be able to produce a ActiveX UserControl that you can utilize in Excel.

Get the Microsoft InteropForms Toolkit 2.1 .

Even though it was originally intended to allow .Net UC usage in VB6, it works fine to write UCs for use in Excel.

As a test, I just wrote one that used the Windows Media Player and it played the video fine as a UserControl on the worksheet.

Start VS as an Admin as it needs to be able to register the control.

Answer (score 0):

I would say build a Form with TopMost = True
Then you can display your webcam video in this Form
and put it anywhere you want.